# Obvious `merge` leads to NA's. How to debug differences between data.tables?

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table` and I am trying to merge them together. 
The first one has the columns: `code` `offers` 
The second one has the columns: `code` `offers` `nb_offers`
I am trying to add the third column to the first data.table through a merge.

The minimal files are available here:

- dt1 = https://ufile.io/vjeju
- dt2 = https://ufile.io/l61jc

My issue is that for some rows, the values aren't filled while they're obviously here.

*A working example*:

```
> library(data.table)
> dt1 <- data.table(readRDS("dt1.rds"))
> dt2 <- data.table(readRDS("dt2.rds"))

> dt1[offers == "0.05"]
    code offers
1: 24428   0.05

> dt2[offers == "0.05"]
    code offers nb_offers
1: 24428   0.05         5

> merge(dt1[offers == "0.05"], dt2[offers == "0.05"], 
        by = c("code", "offers"))
    code offers nb_offers
1: 24428   0.05         5
```

*Let's change things very slightly*:

```
> dt1[offers == "0.06"]
    code offers
1: 24428   0.06

> dt2[offers == "0.06"]
    code offers nb_offers
1: 24428   0.06         3

> merge(dt1[offers == "0.06"], dt2[offers == "0.06"], 
        by = c("code", "offers"))
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: code,offers,nb_offers
```

This makes absolutely no sense to me.

I tried to replicate the error, but if I create the data.tables from scratch, the error doesn't occurr:

```
> tmp1 <- data.table(code = "24428", offers = 0.06)
> tmp2 <- data.table(code = "24428", offers = 0.06, nb_offers = 3)
> setkey(tmp2, code)
> merge(tmp1, tmp2, by = c("code", "offers"))
    code offers nb_offers
1: 24428   0.06         3
> all.equal(tmp1, dt1[offers == "0.06"])
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(tmp2, dt2[offers == "0.06"])
[1] TRUE
```

I understand I can do what I want to do in other ways, but I'd like to understand what's going on here.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't download the files right now, but the first thing i'll check is floating point precision

Comment: From your files, `dt1$offers-0.06` gives `[1] -1.000000e-02  6.938894e-18`, so it is a floating point precision problem. For some reason doing the same with `dt2` gives exactly zero for the second value.

Comment: Try rounding your result before subsetting.

Comment: Yep, that works. I applied `round(x, 2)` to both columns and now the merge works well. 

That's still super weird considering it works for 0.05 (and many others) but not 0.06 (and many others) without clear patterns in what works and what doesn't.
Edit: dt1 comes from text that's been converted with `as.numeric` and dt2 comes from `seq`

Comment: Have a read of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal). Conversion from decimal to binary representations is tricky.